# Is it possible to discard dirty pages on a shared mapping?

Tags: c, linux, mmap

The program I’m working on needs to save some information on every item of its
input.  As the number of items to be processed will be huge, I cannot keep the
data in memory (I iterate over the input in a first pass and record the
information).

I want to place the extra data into virtual memory, but would like it to go to
disk when memory becomes scarce (that’s /when/, not /if/.  It will become scarce).

Currently I create a sparse file of (hopefully) appropriate size, `mmap` the whole
thing, close and unlike the file afterwards.  The reason I unlink the file is that I
don’t need the information as soon as the program quits.

The program can now happily read and write to the mapped region, all is well.

Until the program exists.  Then the kernel starts to write all this now useless
data to disk, although the file is no longer open or linked.  I first thought
that the kernel would realize that the data is no longer accessible, but
apparently not.  So I first included a call to `madvise` with `MDV_REMOVE` at
the end of the program, and as that didn’t help, I also added `MDV_DONTNEED` as
well.  Both didn’t help with my problem.

The worst thing is that this blocks my machine as every write any other program
makes (like my text editor) has to wait for this long running write to complete.

Is there any way to convince the kernel to not write this data to disk?

Comment: Did you try `MAP_ANONYMOUS` instead of a file?

Comment: @rici: No, as I precisely want the mapping to be backed by larger storage.  If I had to use anonymous mapping I could just create objects the regular way.

Comment: @Nathan: `MAP_ANONYMOUS` is backed by swap partitions.

Comment: @myaut: good point.  I’ll look into it.

Comment: @myaut: I just realized this would be a little more involved than I first thought: this is because I resize and remap if the mapping turns out to be too small.  Before I dig into this too much: any anonymous mapping swapped out before other core memory?  I.e. is there a real advantage to using it instead of just allocating objects in core?

Comment: @Nathan likely no. Linux treats anonymous mapping the same it treats anything else. The main advantage is that once your refcount goes to zero, the pages are immediately released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going over the comments, it appears that using the swap is fine for your needs as an alternative to file storage. If that's the case, I think your best bet is to use a file, as you've done, on a tmpfs partition. The best tmpfs partition to use for that purpose is at `/dev/shm`.

Just open a file in `/dev/shm`, truncate it to the size you need, mmap it and unlink, precisely like you've already done. /dev/shm uses the main memory as it's "backing store", but that will get swapped out if memory is short.

The advantage of using the swap is that no force flush will happen to pages that still fit in memory at the point the program exists. Immediately after, these pages are immediately recognized as unneeded, and discarded. This should solve your problem while still allowing you to resize etc.

It has the extra benefit of requiring almost no change to your current code :-)

Comment: That looks like a really nice solution, thanks!  I’ve changed by code to use /dev/shm/ as the directory and running the program right now.  It seems that it immediately allocated some swap storage although there is still memory available, but it also doesn’t seem to be a problem.  I’ll let it run for a large enough input and mark your answer as correct if all goes well.

Comment: This solution is completely untenable as munmap and MADV_DONTNEED behaves exactly the same, freeing *all* pages and not just the dirty ones

Comment: OP describes behavior that directly contradicts your assertion. I also don't think you understand what "untenable" means.